# Javascript querySelector CDATA in xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, cdata

I have this path of my xml file:

```xml
<description>
    <![CDATA[<p class="image"><img width="250" height="83" src="http://www.mydomain.com/picture/pic01.png" class="post-image" alt="Post 01 Image" title="The Demo Post" /></p>My Content
    ]]>
</description>
```

How can i select the **src atribute** of **tag img** in CDATA using querySelector (Javascript).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var description = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("description")[0],
    html = description.innerText || description.textContent,
    root = document.createElement("div"),
    imgsrc;

root.innerHTML = html;
imgsrc = root.querySelector("img").src;
```